# how to sort a two dimensional char array (only column wise) by selection sort in java

Tags: java

**im very new in java i need the whole sorting algorithm....i can find ways to sort a 1 D array but a 2 D array gets very confusing.PLEASE help**

sorry i dont have a code yet, i dont know where to start from! **(this is the code for a one D array:)  but i need one of 2 D (only column wise selection sort)**

```
public static void sort(Comparable[] table) { 
int n = table.length; 
for (int fill=0; fill < n-1; fill++) { 


int posMin = fill; 
for(int next=fill; next < n; next++) { 
if(table[next].compareTo(table[posMin] < 0) {
posMin = next; 

} 
} 
//Exchange table[fill] and table[posMin] 
Comparable temp = table[fill]; 
table[fill] = table[posMin]; 
table[posMin] = temp; 


}
```

Comment: honestly speaking i only posted the code to get my question entered...please please dont flag it i really need help of any sort

Comment: What ordering are you trying to achieve in your 2D array? It's not possible to just have ascending or descending because it's not linear. Do you want, for example, cells in ascending order in each column and columns in descending order of average cell value?

Comment: i need cells in ascending order in each column. the rows are to remain unchanged

Comment: Also, take a look at the various `java.util.Arrays.sort(...)` methods before implementing your own. Unless, of course, you're trying to learn sorting algorithms, in which case you should probably add the homework tag.

Comment: it is prefered to have my own implementation

Comment: AGCAGAAGCGGAGCTTTAAGATGAATATAAATC
GCAGAAGCGGAGCTTTAAGATGAATATAAATCC
CAGAAGCGGAGCTTTAAGATGAATATAAATCCA
AGAAGCGGAGCTTTAAGATGAATATAAATCCAT
GAAGCGGAGCTTTAAGATGAATATAAATCCATA
AAGCGGAGCTTTAAGATGAATATAAATCCATAT
AGCGGAGCTTTAAGATGAATATAAATCCATATT
GCGGAGCTTTAAGATGAATATAAATCCATATTT
CGGAGCTTTAAGATGAATATAAATCCATATTTT
GGAGCTTTAAGATGAATATAAATCCATATTTTC
GAGCTTTAAGATGAATATAAATCCATATTTTCT
AGCTTTAAGATGAATATAAATCCATATTTTCTT
GCTTTAAGATGAATATAAATCCATATTTTCTTT
CTTTAAGATGAATATAAATCCATATTTTCTTTT

Comment: ^THATS how the array is like where the space is actually the enter button

Comment: its actually the RNA sequence of bases,so every read takes a single row and all the reads (no. of reads=no of columns) have to be sorted by selection sort

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, it sounds like you can treat each column as a 1D array, so you can apply your existing 1D solution to each column: wherever you refer to table[x], you can now refer to table[x][c], where c is the column being sorted (or table[c][x]; not certain which index you're using for column).

Answer (score 0):

If you have each DNA sequence be a string, you have a `List` of `Strings`.  Then just sort the strings.

```
List<String> dnaSequences = new ArrayList<String>();
dnaSequences.add("AGCAGAAGCGGAGCTTTAAGATGAATATAAATC");
...
dnaSequences.add("AGCAGAAGCGGAGCTTTAAGATGAATATAAATC");
Collections.sort(dnaSequences);
```